# How to deal with this loop error?[c#]

Tags: c#, loops, debugging

I was working on a project recently about a program that can take a random number out of number in between of 1-10 and let you guess what it is, and you have five chances of guessing it right. But each time I run the program, when I enter a number that is either larger or smaller than the random number, the program instantly depleted my chances like this:

```
You are now playing 'Guess a Number'! The number is going to draw randomly from the range of 1 - 10. Enter the number you think the console drew and you have five chances to guess! Good luck!
5
The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have 4 chances left.
The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have 3 chances left.
The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have 2 chances left.
The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have 1 chances left.
The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have 0 chances left.
Sorry, you have no more guesses.
```

Here are the original codes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool quit = false;
        while (!quit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are now playing 'Guess a Number'! The number is going to draw randomly from the range of 1 - 10. Enter the number you think the console drew and you have five chances to guess! Good luck!");
            Random random = new Random();
            bool guessingNumber = true;
            int guesses = 5;
            int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 10);
            string playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> num = new List<int>();
            int oneNum;
            if (int.TryParse(playerGuess, out oneNum))
            {
               num.Add(oneNum);
            }

            while(guessingNumber)
            {
                if (oneNum < randomNumber)
                {
                    guesses--;
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is smaller than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);
                    break;
                }

                if (oneNum > randomNumber)
                {
                    guesses--;
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);
                }

                if (oneNum == randomNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You have guessed the right number!");
                }

                if (guesses == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you have no more guesses.");
                    guessingNumber = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me find the problem since I have a really hard time trying to do it, thank you!

Comment: You have `guessingNumber=true` so it goes in while loop. and it does `guesses--;` because `oneNum != randomNumber`. Also `guessess !=0` so it doesn't do `guessingNumber = false;` so it again goes in to while loop and repeats the same thing until `guesses` becomes `0` and gets out of the loop at the end. You need to debug the code observe how the code behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mainly have made two mistakes.

First, you did not read new input in each iteration of the loop, so if the input is wrong, the while loop loops back, sees the same input, compare it with the random number, get the same result, next iteration...

To correct this, move the code that reads input to the start of the while loop:

```
while (guessingNumber)
{
    playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(playerGuess, out oneNum))
    {
        num.Add(oneNum);
    }
    ...
```

Secondly, you should not `break` out of the loop if the guess is smaller. You should `break` when the guess is correct.

```
if (oneNum < randomNumber)
{
    guesses--;
    Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is smaller than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);
    // don't break here!

}

if (oneNum > randomNumber)
{
    guesses--;
    Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);
}

if (oneNum == randomNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You have guessed the right number!");
    break; // add this!
}
```

Comment: And also the guess variable should be static as well as checked.

Answer (score 0):

if number is greater or lesser than random number you need to make guessingNumber=false and guess counter must be out of the first while loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool quit = false;
            int guesses = 5;

            while (!quit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are now playing 'Guess a Number'! The number is going to draw randomly from the range of 1 - 10. Enter the number you think the console drew and you have five chances to guess! Good luck!");
                Random random = new Random();
                bool guessingNumber = true;

                int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 10);
                string playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();
                List<int> num = new List<int>();
                int oneNum;
                if (int.TryParse(playerGuess, out oneNum))
                {
                    num.Add(oneNum);
                }

                while (guessingNumber)
                {
                    if (oneNum < randomNumber)
                    {
                        guesses--;
                        Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is smaller than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);
                        guessingNumber = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (oneNum > randomNumber)
                    {
                        guesses--;
                        Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is larger than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);
                        guessingNumber = false;
                    }

                    if (oneNum == randomNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You have guessed the right number!");
                        guessingNumber = false;
                    }

                    if (guesses == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you have no more guesses.");
                        guessingNumber = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool quit = false;

        Random random = new Random();

        int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 10);

        Console.WriteLine("You are now playing 'Guess a Number'! The number is going to draw randomly from the range of 1 - 10. Enter the number you think the console drew and you have five chances to guess! Good luck!");

        List<int> num = new List<int>();
        int guesses = 5;

        while (!quit)
        {

            string playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();

            int oneNum;

            if (int.TryParse(playerGuess, out oneNum))
            {
                num.Add(oneNum);
            }
            var lastNum = num.Last();


            if (guesses == 0) //the guesses times should be checked first.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you have no more guesses.");
                break;
            }
            if (lastNum < randomNumber)//the list's last element was your input number.
            {
                guesses--;
                Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is smaller than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);

            }

            if (lastNum > randomNumber)
            {
                guesses--;
                Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is bigger than the random number, you have {0} chances left.", guesses);

            }

            if (lastNum==randomNumber)//if  equals
            {
                quit = true;//set the flag to end loop
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You have guessed the right number!");
            }


        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```